# JSON.deserialize returns null after deserialize

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

I've created controller to my Aura Component and it works.

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class B2B_RegisterFormController {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createLead(String lead, Boolean isWholesalePartner){
        
        WrapperLead obj = (WrapperLead)JSON.deserialize(lead, WrapperLead.class);
        Lead leadToInsert = new Lead();
        Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
            .get('Potential_commerce_client').getRecordTypeId();
        Datetime now = DateTime.now();       
        
        AssignmentRule AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Lead' and Active = true limit 1];
        Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;
        dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
        
        leadToInsert.FirstName = obj.firstName;
        leadToInsert.LastName = obj.lastName;
        leadToInsert.Title = obj.jobTitle;
        leadToInsert.Email = obj.email;
        leadToInsert.Phone = obj.phone;
        leadToInsert.Company = obj.company;
        leadToInsert.Legal_form__c = obj.legalForm;
        leadToInsert.Contact_Person__c = obj.contactPerson;
        leadToInsert.Number_of_buyers__c = obj.numberOfBuyers;
        leadToInsert.Store_count__c = obj.storeCount;
        leadToInsert.Website = obj.website;
        leadToInsert.Street = obj.street;
        leadToInsert.City = obj.city;
        leadToInsert.PostalCode = obj.postalCode;
        leadToInsert.Country = obj.country;
        leadToInsert.State = obj.state; 
        leadToInsert.Description = obj.companyDescription;
        leadToInsert.Select_products__c = obj.selectProducts;
        System.debug('isCoverAllRegions after deserialize: ' + obj.isCoverAllRegions);
        leadToInsert.Is_cover_all_regions_within_your_country__c = obj.isCoverAllRegions;
        leadToInsert.States_or_regions__c = obj.statesOrRegions;
        
        leadToInsert.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
        leadToInsert.Lead_conversion_deadline__c = now.addHours(6);
        leadToInsert.is_Wholesale_B2B_Partner__c = isWholesalePartner;
        leadToInsert.setOptions(dmlOpts);
        
        if(lead != null && !String.isEmpty(lead) && isWholesalePartner != null){
            try {                
                insert leadToInsert;
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wrapper class

```
public class WrapperLead {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String firstName{get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String lastName{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String jobTitle{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String email{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String phone{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String company{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String legalForm{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String contactPerson{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String numberOfBuyers{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String storeCount{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String website{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String street{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String city{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String postalCode{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String country{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String state{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String companyDescription{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String selectProducts{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isCoverAllRegions{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String statesOrRegions{get;set;}
   
}
```

**Controller Test**

```
@IsTest
public class B2B_RegisterFormControllerTest {
    
    @IsTest
    static void testCreateLead() {

        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.FirstName = 'test';
        newLead.LastName = 'user';
        newLead.Email = 'test@mail.com';
        newLead.Company = 'company'; 
        
        newLead.Title = 'title';
        newLead.Phone = '1234';
        newLead.Legal_form__c = null;
        newLead.Contact_Person__c = 'test';
        newLead.Number_of_buyers__c = null;
        newLead.Store_count__c = null;
        newLead.Website = 'http://www.test.pl';
        newLead.Street = 'test';
        newLead.City = 'test';
        newLead.PostalCode = '1234';
        newLead.Country = 'test';
        newLead.State = 'test'; 
        newLead.Description = 'test';
        newLead.Select_products__c = null;
        newLead.Is_cover_all_regions_within_your_country__c = true;
        newLead.States_or_regions__c = null;    

        //given        

        System.debug('isCover before serialize (in test) ' + newLead.Is_cover_all_regions_within_your_country__c);
        String leadData = JSON.serialize(newLead);
        System.debug('leadData after serialize (in test) ' + leadData);
        Boolean isWholesalePartner = false;
        List<Lead> listOfLeadsBeforeInsert = [SELECT Id FROM Lead];
        
        //when
        B2B_RegisterFormController.createLead(leadData, isWholesalePartner);        
        List<Lead> listOfLeadsAfterInsert = [SELECT Id FROM Lead];
        
        //then
        System.assertNotEquals(listOfLeadsBeforeInsert.size(), listOfLeadsAfterInsert.size());
        System.assertEquals(listOfLeadsBeforeInsert.size(), listOfLeadsAfterInsert.size()-1);

    }
}
```

The problem is that - my component works as it should but my tests not - after deserialize obj.isCoverAllRegions returns null (there is true in JSON after serialize). In advices how to resolve this?

Comment: Hello Pawel, and welcome to SFSE, is there any particular reason why in our test it serializes `Lead` instead of `WrapperLead`? It seems to have a mismatch between the test and the actual class which could be the culprit.

Comment: I don't know. That was my idea to create tests for createLead method...

Comment: Fair enough, I suggest you replace on test the usage of `Lead` with `WrapperLead` and tell the results.

Comment: Thanks @JefersonChaves, it works